# powershell: add user to local admin group

Tags: windows, powershell

i am trying to create user on remote machine by powershell. Once account created i want to add that in local admin group.

Account is getting created but it is not getting added in admin group.
Below is the code which i am using.

```
  cls
  $username = "test_user"
$password = "password"
$computer1 = hostname
  $users = $null
   $computer = [ADSI]“WinNT://$computer1”
   Try {
      $users = $computer.psbase.children | select -expand name  
      if ($users -like $username) {
         Write-Host "$username already exists"
      } Else {
         $user_obj = $computer.Create(“user”, “$username”)
         $user_obj.SetPassword($password)
         $user_obj.SetInfo()

         $user_obj.Put(“description”, “$username”)
         $user_obj.SetInfo()
         $user_obj.psbase.invokeset(“AccountDisabled”, “False”)
         $user_obj.SetInfo()
         $users = $computer.psbase.children | select -expand name
         if ($users -like $username) {
            Write-Host "$username has been created on $($computer.name)"

      $group = [ADSI]("WinNT://"+$env:COMPUTERNAME+"/administrators,group")
$group.add("WinNT://$env:localhost/$username,user")


         } Else {


            Write-Host "$username has not been created on $($computer.name)"
         }
      }
   } Catch {
      Write-Host "Error creating $username on $($computer.path):  $($Error[0].Exception.Message)"
   }
```

Please advise what am i doing wrong.

Comment: You have a typo on your add to the group line, should be: `$group.add("WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/$username,user")`

Comment: _Off-topic_: use `$users = ($computer.psbase.children | Where-Object {$_.Properties['UserFlags']}).Name` to get only user names and `if ($users -contains $username) {` to check `$username` existence.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the script that was copied and pasted does not work at all.

It has invalid double quotes: `“` and `”`

It references the local computer in three different ways:

`[ADSI]“WinNT://$computer1”`
`[ADSI]("WinNT://"+$env:COMPUTERNAME+"`
`WinNT://$env:localhost/`

There are several occurrences where text is not quoted properly and separated/concatenated with variables.

This works:

```
cls
$username = "test_user"
$password = "zlug7nPn5$"
$computername = "ComputerName"
$users = $null
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computername"
Try {
   $users = $computer.psbase.children | select -expand name
   if ($users -like $username) {
      Write-Host "$username already exists"
   } Else {
      $user_obj = $computer.Create("user", "$username")
      $user_obj.SetPassword($password)
      $user_obj.SetInfo()

      $user_obj.Put("description", "$username")
      $user_obj.SetInfo()
      $user_obj.psbase.invokeset("AccountDisabled", "False")
      $user_obj.SetInfo()
      $users = $computer.psbase.children | select -expand name
      if ($users -like $username) {
         Write-Host "$username has been created on $($computer.name)"

      $group = [ADSI]("WinNT://"+$computername+"/administrators,group")
      $group.add("WinNT://"+$computername+"/"+$username+",user")
      } Else {
         Write-Host "$username has not been created on $($computer.name)"
      }
   }
} Catch {
   Write-Host "Error creating $username on $($computer.path):  $($Error[0].Exception.Message)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using Add-localgroupmember command?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/add-localgroupmember

Same with user creation, New-Localuser.